# Python equivalent to Solidity u256

Tags: python, solidity, web3py

I am working on a Solidity Smart Contract. The idea is to automate some of the tasks using Python. So I have this code:

```
idx = 1
event_id = cDF.iloc[idx]["A"].astype(int)
event_date = cDF.iloc[idx]["B"].astype(int)
x = cDF.iloc[idx]["C"].astype(int)
y = cDF.iloc[idx]["D"].astype(int)

a = 69295
print(type(a))
print(type(event_id))

txcreation_txn = contract.functions.publishEvent(event_id, event_date, x, y).buildTransaction({
    'from': <some_testing_wallet>, 
    'value': 0,
    'gas': 3000000000000,
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('1', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce_var})
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txcreation_txn, private_key=private_key)
result = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(f"result # {idx} - {result.hex()}")
```

for which I get the following error:

```
Could not identify the intended function with name `publishEvent`, positional argument(s) of type 
`(<class 'numpy.int64'>, <class 'numpy.int64'>, <class 'numpy.int64'>, <class 'numpy.int64'>)` and keyword 
argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `publishEvent`: ['publishEvent(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```

However, it works and send the tx to the blockchain when I ran this manually:

```
betcreation_txn = contract.functions.publishEvent(69295,1628516242331,24,28)
.buildTransaction({'from': '0xDaf36E4570e2f0A587331b8E1E3645Ce8861B6A5', 'value': 0,
'gas': 3000000,'gasPrice': w3.toWei('1', 'gwei'),'nonce': nonce_var})
```

the function signature in Solidity:

```
  function publishEvent(uint256 _event_id, uint256 _event_date, uint256 _x, uint256 _y) payable public
```

So I guess the issue is that the data I am sending from Python is not compatible with Solidity u256. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: ```betcreation_txn = contract.functions.publishEvent(69295,1628516242331,24,28).buildTransaction({'from': <wallet>, 'value': 0,'gas': 3000000,'gasPrice': w3.toWei('1', 'gwei'),'nonce': nonce_var})```

```signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(betcreation_txn, private_key=pk)```

```result = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)``` 

this is the code...this works with 'publishEvent(69295,1628516242331,24,28)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd convert your `x` and `y` to this, like so:

```py
x = cDF.iloc[idx]["C"].astype(int).item()
y = cDF.iloc[idx]["D"].astype(int).item()
```

EDIT: I have refactored this answer to convert the numpy `int64`'s to Python `int`'s using the numpy [item() method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer...I am getting this error now...

```TypeError: Unsupported type: '<class 'numpy.int64'>'.  Must be one of: bool, str, bytes, bytearrayor int.```

Comment: @MartinRasumoff just gave it an edit, let me know how that works.

Comment: thanks a lot sir....no, it did not...it is converting it as strings now:

```ValidationError:
Could not identify the intended function with name `publishEvent`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `publishEvent`: ['publishEvent(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```
have been working on this for 2 days now :(

thanks for any pointer...

Comment: @MartinRasumoff try giving that answer a go, get rid of the toHex lines, and just use this `x` and `y`

Comment: YES!!!!! now I am getting a gas error but at least not the data type!!!! Thanks a lot sir!!!!!

Comment: @MartinRasumoff :) happy coding, Solidity / Python / Numpy data types are a bit of a headache to deal with sometimes.